# How to pass children to React Reusable components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to make a reusable components with passing other components in specific way like what UI libraries do.

For example let's say I wanna build a Card component,

One possible way is to pass the components just like props :

```
return (
  <Card
    header={<MyHeader />}
    body={<MyBody />}
  />
)
```

But I was wondering how its done when we call it this way :

```
return (
  <Card>
    <Card.Header> 
      // I can put whatever I want here ...
    </Card.Header>

    <Card.Body>
      <div>
        // The same goes here too ..
      </div>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
);
```

Is there an easy way to do this with functional components ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is very simple that you cannot imagine it, just make the `Body` and `Header` component separately in the `Card` component folder and in the `index.js` of the `Card` component import both of them. attach to the `Card` component and then `export default Card`. it could be [the form](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/form/index.tsx) component of `ant.design`:

The `Head` component in its separated file:

```js
import React from "react";

const Head = () => (
    <div>
        // some codes
    </div>
);

export default Head;
```

The `Body` component in its separated file:

```js
import React from "react";

const Body = () => (
    <div>
        // some codes
    </div>
);

export default Body;
```

Now in the `index.js` file that creates the `Card` component:

```js
import React from "react";
import Head from "./Head";
import Body from "./Body";

const Card = () => (
    <div>
        // some codes
    </div>
);

Card.Head = Head;
Card.Body = Body;

export default Card;
```

Now, anywhere when you import the `Card` component you can access to the `Body` and `Head` just like you want:

```js
import Head from "[pathToCardComponent]/Card";

~~~

<Card>
  <Card.Head>header</Card.Head>
  <Card.Body>body</Card.Body>
</Card>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Im sorry Im afraid I may have done a poor job on explaining the question.
What I want to do is to implement this "Card" component.
I've seen in UI libraries such as Semantic UI they use this dot notation (Card.Header ) but I don't know how is that handled.